# How to update existing object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to update current object within an array with new property using state hooks. The array with object looks like this:

```
const myData = [
   {
     dataLabels: [
        {
           align: 'left'
        }
     ],
     name: 'my data',
     data: [
       {
         y: 1,
         name: 'Daryl'
       },
       {
         y: 2,
         name: 'Negan'
       }
     ]
   }
 ];
```

and I wan't to add color property to data objects inside `useState` hook. This is what I've tried so far:

```
const [ newMyData ] = useState({
   ...myData,
   0: { 
     ...myData[0],
     data: myData[0].data.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, color: getChartColors()[index] }))
   },
 });
```

but the problem is that `newMyData` is now turned into an object instead of keep being an array. What am I doing wrong and how should I solve my problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: You are actually giving useState an object. try giving him an array

Comment: @QuentinGrisel Yeah, that was the problem. But how to write the logic for this? Because I want to overwrite the 0 property there, and within square brackets, it won't work

Comment: Try using `Array.from(yourObject)` then if you need an array. But useState is made to give a default value to `newMyData`. If you want to update it later (by overwriting the 0), yu need to use a setter: `const [myNewData, setMyNewData] = useState(YourDefaultArray)` and then call `setMyNewData(YourNewArray)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an object as the initial state:

```
const [ newMyData ] = useState([ /* <--- use '[' not '{' */
   ...myData,
   0: { 
     ...myData[0],
     data: myData[0].data.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, color: getChartColors()[index] }))
   },
 ] /* <--- same here - use ']' not '}' */ );
```

UPDATE:

Based on what you asked in the comments:

```
const myData = [
   {
     dataLabels: [
        {
           align: 'left'
        }
     ],
     name: 'my data',
     data: [
       {
         y: 1,
         name: 'Daryl'
       },
       {
         y: 2,
         name: 'Negan'
       }
     ]
   }
 ];

const myObject = myData[0];

const nextObject = {
    ...myObject,
    data: myObject.data.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, color: getChartColors()[index] }))

}

const [myData, setMyData] = useState([ nextObject ]); /* If you still want this to be an array */

/* OR */

const [myData, setMyData] = useState( nextObject ); /* If you want it to be an object instead */
```

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. But how to write the logic for this? Because I want to overwrite the 0 property there, and within square brackets, it won't work

Comment: @Milos Are there other elements in the original array?

Comment: No, just the way I've posted

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can follow this example to include new property in array using useState hooks.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

export default function UseStateExample() {
    const [myData, setMyData] = useState([
        {
            dataLabels: [
                {align: 'left'}
            ],
            name: 'my data',
            data: [
                {y: 1, name: 'Daryl'},
                {y: 2, name: 'Negan'}
            ]
        }
    ]);

    function getChartColors() {
        return ["red", "green", "blue"]
    }
    function clickHandler(event) {

        let items = [];
        myData[0].data.map((item, index) => {
            item.color = getChartColors()[index];
            items.push(item);
        });

        setMyData([
            ...myData
        ]);

        console.log(myData)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={clickHandler}>Update myData and show in Console</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```